# monkeyrunner and broadcastIntent

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

Can someone share example of using Monkeyrunners broadcastIntent method. To run Browser with certain webpage for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well precisely, broadcasting an intent will trigger the broadcast receivers.
If you want to start the browser from monkeyrunner you can use the below mentioned code

```
def browse(d):
    d.broadcastIntent("http://www.google.com/", "ACTION_MAIN")
```